# Why @Transactional is not prolonged to repository method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to perform several operations in one transaction.

I use org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

One service (with @Transactional) calls another (without @Transactional) and this service calls repository

I have next service

```
    @Transactional
    public void performBatchOperations( List<String> ids) {
      service1.doAction(ids);
      service2.doAction(ids);
    }
```

service2

```
@Component
public class Service2 {
   @Autowired
   private Repo repo;

  public void doAction(List<String> ids){
  repo.delete(ids);
}
```

Repository

```
@Component
public class Repo extends
    JpaRepository<Entity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Entity>{


  @Modifying
  @Query("DELETE FROM Entity a WHERE a.jobId IN :ids")
  void deleteByJobIdIn(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);
}
```

I got next error

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
liberty-debug    |  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:99)
```

But i have @Transactional on my service method. Why it wasn't prolonged to Repository?

Is there way to use @Modifying as part of complex transaction?

Comment: Is the rest of spring properly set up?

Comment: which transactional are you using? (what are you importing)?

Comment: Check that you're **always** using `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` and not mixing it with `@javax.transaction.Transactional`

Comment: This may not be documented clearly, but it is expected that `@Modifying` methods are also annotated with `@Transactional`. Doing so will propagate the running transaction to the repository method, as expected. In fact, the official documentation recommends annotating all repository interfaces as `@Transactional(readOnly = true`). The exception is seen because the proxy generated by Spring Data has no way of knowing if a repository method **will always be invoked within a transaction**, since the method can as well be called from a non-transactional context (after all, it is a `public` method).

Comment: Can I use @Modifying as part of complex transaction?